# oracle truncates the value after saving an id with precisions?

Tags: oracle

I have a table. it has a column with datatype **NUMBER(38,20)**. it is an id column. out application generates the id. i am trying to insert record with an id value of 105.00010. but it inserts only 105.0001. May i know the reason why it is truncating one value(0). it porperly inserts records from 105.00001 to 105.00009. while inserting 105.00010 it is truncating. Please help me.

column size is `**NUMBER(38,20)**`

Thanks!

Comment: `105.00010` is **exactly** the same value as `105.0001`. Nothing was truncated.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. now if i save a record with an id of 105.0001 then does it overrides previous record?

Comment: When you update a value in a column, then of course the previous value will be overwritten. What exactly is your question?

Comment: consider initially i have saved a record with an id of 105.00010. but oracle inserted the record with an id of 105.0001 and truncated 0. now second time i have a record with 105.0001, while saving this record overrides the previous one with an id of 105.0001(actually 105.00010). please help me.

Comment: Again: **nothing was truncated**, `105.00010` and `105.0001` are **exactly the same values**. You are replacing the stored value with exactly the same value again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following test case:

```
WITH data_values
  AS (SELECT 105.0001 AS test_val FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 105.00010 AS test_val FROM dual)
SELECT test_val,
       TO_NUMBER(test_val, '999.99999') AS NUM,
       TO_CHAR(test_val, '999.99999') AS STR
  FROM data_values;
```

Results in:

```
TEST_VAL NUM      STR
105.0001 105.0001 105.00010
105.0001 105.0001 105.00010
```

The value after the final non zero digit is irrelevent to Oracle. Both your numbers are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The rightmost zeros after the decimal are insignificant, so the value is not truncated, it is still the same value.

If you need it to stay the same you may need to treat the value as a varchar2.

Comment: Thanks for replying. i am viewing this id in sqldeveloper. here it appears as if it is truncated. but the same i have queries using pl/sql developer. here i am getting all precisions. why sqldeveloper is showing like this? please help me.

Comment: You need to set your default character mask for displaying numeric data in your preferences for SQLDeveloper.

Comment: @user1016403 SQLDeveloper has settings for how to display certain types under tools/preferences.

Comment: Go to Tools -> Preferences then under "Database" click on "NLS" change the format masks there. For a full description of the available numeric masks look: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm